# How to keep JavaScript values between multiple pages in one session?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I have this code:

```
from selenium.common import TimeoutException, WebDriverException
from selenium import webdriver
import sys


class Main:
    def _init_(self, page_url):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.element_list = []
        self.page_url = page_url

    def javascript(self):
        self.driver.get(self.page_url)
        js_script = """
        //Callback function
        var done = arguments[arguments.length - 1]; 
        //Take all the events
        var array_events = []
    
        var registerOuterHtml = (e) => {
            array_events.push
            (e.target.outerHTML)
        }
        var whole = (e) => {
            array_events.push
            (document.documentElement.outerHTML)
        }
        var quit = (key) => {
            console.log(array_events);
            (key.keyCode == 27 )? done(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array_events))) :
             undefined
        }
        // Listen to the clicks
        getElementHtml = document.addEventListener("click", registerOuterHtml, true)
        getDOMHtml = document.addEventListener("click", whole, true)
        // Listen to the key "esc" which means user has gathered all needed events
        getKey = document.addEventListener("keydown", quit, true)

        """
        self.driver.set_script_timeout(10000)
        try:
            try:
                response = self.driver.execute_async_script(js_script)
                print(len(response) / 2) #should print the number of times you have clicked for testing purposes
            except TimeoutException:
                print('Program closed after 10,000 seconds !')
                self.driver.quit()
                sys.exit()
        except WebDriverException:
            print(WebDriverException)
            print('Driver may be closed incorrectly or unknown error occurred!')
            return False
```

This python code starts a chrome browser with selenium, then the user should click some elements in the page, where the click gets some value using the javascript function being executed by driver.execute_async_script,and then the function is closed when pressing 'esc' button, closing window and returing values as well.
It all works fine, but if the user clicks some elements in the original page and then goes to a different page and clicks some more, the values from the previous page don't get returned (the DOM changes, so the new DOM with the fresh script obviously doesn't know anything what happened before)

I have tried storing the variable array_events in localStorage or sessionStorage, but it returns invalid, so I haven't been able to fix this.

I want the answer to be the JavaScript code correct and ready to be able to handle this task.

Comment: It probably can't be done with selenium because once the user navigates there is no chance of execute_async_script resolving.

Comment: It's not possible. The solution is to store the values in localStorage but you already said you've tried this. The other work-around is to send the value back to your python script and store it in python instead of javascript. Then when you navigate to another page have the python script inject the value back to javascript.

Comment: Sometimes unfortunately the answer you are looking for is "there is no answer to this question" or "it is impossible". You need to find another way to do what you want to do.

Comment: What do you mean is not possible? Everything is possible!